# Knockout Observable and Time

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I use Knockout and Typescript on my project and I need to build in the view model three fields that will have the datetime type. Those will need to be updated when a condition is meet.

What I have:

View:

```
    <div data-bind="if: step1CompleteY">
    <span data-bind="text: step1CompleteY" />
    <input type="datetime" data-bind="value: timestampSt1()" />
</div>
<div data-bind="if: step12Complete">
    <span data-bind="text: step12Complete" />
    <input type="datetime" data-bind="value: timestampSt2()" />
</div>
<div data-bind="if: step23Complete">
    <span data-bind="text: step23Complete" />
    <input type="datetime" data-bind="value: timestampSt3()" />
</div>
```

View Model:

```
myTimestamp = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes());    
timestampSt1 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
timestampSt2 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
timestampSt3 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
step1CompleteY = ko.computed({
    read: () => this.objectChecks.exportValue() === 'Yes' 
})
step12Complete = ko.computed({
    read: () => { return this.objectChecks.exportValue() === 'No' || this.objectChecks.rfqStatusValue() === 'Approved' }
})
step23Complete = ko.computed({
    read: () => { return (this.objectChecks.indemnityValue() === 'Yes' || this.objectChecks.indemnityValue() === 'N/A' || this.objectChecks.rfqStatusValue() === "Denied") }
})
```

The problem here is, that the date time appear and I don't know how to use "setTimeout" to work with this observables and basically to have that time refreshed only when the conditions are meet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your values in following way. If there is no relationship between 3 time stamps. 
I will declare  different time stamps to avoid confusion.

```
myTimestamp1 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes()); 

myTimestamp2 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes());  

myTimestamp3 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes());
```

Here as your are defining computed on completion of the steps values of current new time stamp will be calculated and will not be repeated what was on page refresh.

```
step1CompleteY = ko.computed({
    read: () => this.objectChecks.exportValue() === 'Yes';

    myTimestamp1 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes()); 
})

step12Complete = ko.computed({
    read: () => { return this.objectChecks.exportValue() === 'No' || this.objectChecks.rfqStatusValue() === 'Approved' }

myTimestamp2 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes());  
    })

step23Complete = ko.computed({
    read: () => { return (this.objectChecks.indemnityValue() === 'Yes' || this.objectChecks.indemnityValue() === 'N/A' || this.objectChecks.rfqStatusValue() === "Denied") }



myTimestamp3 = ko.observable(new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes()); 
    })
```

Here if values of each time stamp will be reflected. And problem of on refresh will be resolved

```
timestampSt1 = ko.observable(myTimestamp1);
timestampSt2 = ko.observable(myTimestamp2);
timestampSt3 = ko.observable(myTimestamp3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **First Rule of Knockout** is that *observables are functions*. `myTimestamp` is a function, so when you write

```
timestampSt1 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
timestampSt2 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
timestampSt3 = ko.observable(this.myTimestamp);
```

You've defined three observables which store a *function*, not the timestamp value.

Try this:

```
// don't call new Date several times - there is a very small chance the value will change between each call.
var d = new Date();
// create a string from the date
var timestamp = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes());
myTimestamp = ko.observable(timestamp);
timestampSt1 = ko.observable(timestamp);
timestampSt2 = ko.observable(timestamp);
timestampSt3 = ko.observable(timestamp);
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggetion and you are right with the writting. Now having this how can I do, to have the timestampSt1, timestampSt2 taking different values based on the moment when the condition becomes true. Right now the timestamp is reflected with the value when the page it is refreshed.

Comment: Don't do this: `data-bind="value: timestampSt1()"` - try this instead: `data-bind="value: timestampSt1"` The first won't bind the value correctly - it will read it but won't write it back

Comment: I've already tried this and returns: Unexpected call to method or property access.

Comment: We have no idea of the wider picture, I'm guessing the binding is in the wrong context. I'm also not clear on when/how you are expecting to update the values. In your example they are bound to an input box, which suggests the user is going to enter it.